# Accounts of the proof of Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, alternative-proof

I would like to collect a set of references to pieces of Wiles' 1995 proof of Fermat's Last Theorem. Has anyone recompiled the proof into another paper? Are there any books or articles that describe interesting portions or prerequisites to the proof? The goal here is not layman's math, but actual proofs.

Wiles' proof is widely regarded as a monumentous achievement, receiving rare fame in the nonmathematical press, yet there has seemingly been little work to digest and reproduce the proof by other authors (a process which usually results in streamlining and increasing the comprehensibility of the proof). I am interested in gathering all such secondary references to the proof to get a good overview of how it could be made precise.

Comment: Check this book: http://www.amazon.com/First-Course-Modular-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/038723229X

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively accessible and complete account:
https://www.math.wisc.edu/~boston/869.pdf